# Why is my text is extending the width of the div? (Not due to word-wrap or overflow-wrap attributes)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, frontend

I am trying to load notifications in my app into a dropdown from my navbar (which is a bootstrap navbar). The partials that I am working with for each notification are similar to this one:

```
<%= link_to student_path(notification.notifiable), class: "dropdown-item notification-row #{"unread" if !notification.read_at?}" do %>
  <%= image_tag notification.faculty.photo, class: "avatar", alt: "faculty-pic" %>
  <div class="notification-message">
    <%= notification.faculty.teacher_name %>
    <%= notification.action %>
    <%= notification.notifiable.first_name %>
    <%= notification.notifiable.last_name %>
    to you
  </div>
  <div class="notification-time"><%= time_ago_in_words(notification.created_at) %></div>
<% end %>
```

I am specifically attempting to keep the "notification-message" class at a width of 200 px as displayed in my css:

```
.notification-message {
    width: 200px;
}
```

but my partials do not render accordingly...

[image]

I want the "notification-message" content to wrap within that width so that my notifications are consistent. I have tried adding both the word-wrap, and overflow-wrap attributes to my css, but they do not help (my partial is rendered just the same). Is this happening because of some sort of bootstrap style? Any other ideas??

Comment: It will be easier if you show generated html with css for classes

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @blazpie what do you mean by that? I apply style directly in the html?

Comment: Inline css is not working either